# wxPython -- How to update the border style of BitmapButton in some event say click

Tags: python, button, bitmap, wxpython, border

I am trying to add/remove border of BitmapButton AFTER the button been created. I haven't find any working example to update the appearance of BitmapButton. Say

```
self.btn = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, bmp, pos=(...))
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, self.btn)
```

Then in OnClick

```
def OnClick(self):
    # what should be here to give / remove the border of the button being clicked
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use methods like `SetWindowStyle()` or `SetWindowStyleFlag()`, which are implemented by `wx.Window`, a common ancestor for all wxWidgets windows, and documented [here](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html).

For example, for the border, try this:

```
btn.SetWindowStyleFlag(wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
# or
btn.SetWindowStyleFlag(wx.NO_BORDER)
```

Comment: to get this to work on a wx.Panel I had to add the flag wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE and then resize the panel 1 pixel larger and resize it again back to the original size